# How to save $_SERVER vars to string

Tags: php

## Solved

This is a basic example of what I want to do:

```
$installURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$save= $installURL;
$str = str_replace( '/setup', '', $save ); //remove /setup/
$installURL= $save;
```

I am trying to save the `$_SERVER` variables to a string, and then remove a certain portion of the new string.

Currently, the above code does not work.

The current output is: `http://localhost/amdin/setup`

I thought the `str_replace` would remove that last part. I really want to `str_replace` remove this instead of using other `$_SERVER` variables.

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: @yogu, whoops, forgot to add that ..just a sec :P

Comment: why don't you do just $installURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/admin';?

Comment: @LucaBorrione This is a distributive open-source program. I con't know where users will install it yet. I do however know, that it can't currently be installed on a HTTPS server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct the last line:

```
$installURL= $save;
```

to

```
$installURL= $str;
```

Comment: I'll mark as answer as soon as it will let me. Currently 5 mins away.

Comment: Answer recorded. Time to make another pot of coffee :P